# Reload ListView by an OnClickListener in a SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, button, simplecursoradapter

I have 2 buttons on every item of the list view. One for editing and another for deleting the item of the listView. Now the problem is to reload the list. How can I do this?

```
        Button delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.NewOrder_delete_Btn);

        if(delete.getTag()!=null)delete.setTag(ItemForEditing);
        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {               
                        SQLAdapter myDB = new SQLAdapter(act);
                        myDB.open();
                        myDB.DeleteOneOrderItem(view.getTag().toString());
                myDB.close();    
                 }
                });
```

Comment: use notifyDataSetChanged() for adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting record from DB, you need to call the following method to refresh it's contents:

```
yourListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

you may call it right after *myDB.close();*